# Repeat the 2nd tablix per page in a SSRS report Irrespective of first tablix value

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an `SSRS` report. It an have 2 `tablix` Regions. First `tablix` is showing Report Data and second `tablix` is showing Error message description. there is no page-break defined in the report, so the first `tablix` displays data in multiple pages. However I need show the 2nd `tablix` in each page. How to achieve this? Currently the report showing 2nd `tablix` after first `tablix` data . How to repeat the 2nd `tablix` per page in a `SSRS report` irrespective of first `tablix` value

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can't repeat tablix with respect to other but you can apply on textbox control with **repeatwith** properties to tablix id.

Comment: Yeah. i tried to do the values by using textbox instead of tablix. but it shows only the first row. I added texbox in the footer and tried this. Could you tell me is it possible to footer so that it will show on each page irrespective of the first tablix values?

Comment: You might be able to just display all of the values in the textbox instead of only the first.  Try setting the textbox's expression to a Join function with vbCrLf as the delimiter.